# Which key mode is funk saxophone played in?

Tags: theory, saxophone, key, modes

I am analysing the musical style of playing saxophone on dance beats, or dubstep, like in [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=WhBoR_tgXCI#t=174).

Would you characterise this as funk? And what is the key they use. My closest guess is a minor or major blues scale, but I could be totally wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't call this funk - it's too upbeat, not relaxed and soulful enough. I think you're right on the key - the basis is minor pentatonic scale ("blues scale"), I think I heard a few embellishments that use aeolian or dorian, and I notied a diminished fifth here and there. But basis is def. minor pentatonic.

Comment: This song is not funk, and it's in a regular minor key (no fancy modes here)

Comment: @RolandBouman - the minor pentatonic with a diminshed(flattened) fifth is the blues.

Comment: @Tim I stand corrected. Thanks for pointing it out - I didn't realize "blues scale" was in fact defined like that.

Comment: Isn't blues scale almost a (modern) dorian with diminished fifth even? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: @dorien - it's not really. Most would say it's the minor pent. with the addition of a b5 (or #4), usually called the former.Yes, lots of other notes are used frequently in playing the blues, funnily enough the maj.3rd, which somehow doesn't feature in the 'blues scale'. Odd perhaps.

Comment: @dorien, dorian is the minor pentatonic + major 2nd + major 6th. The blues scale is the minor pentatonic + the sharp fourth. Yes they have the hole pentatonic scale in common but almost all minor modes do (with the exception of locrian) ; phrygian, aolian, and dorian all include the five notes of the pentatonic scale but they sound very different. Learn to use the major 6th in a minor context, and the flat 7 in a major context (mixolydian mode). This link explains funk harmony and gives some examples : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funk#Harmony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No.   2. C blues.   Really, that's all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

Minor pentationic and Dorian are fairly popular in funk. Experiment with Dorian, it's one scale you must learn if you're into funk.

Comment: I second that. Dorian is very effective for funk.

Comment: Thanks I will surely look into it. I am guessing it would fit my style as my name is Dorien :)